# How to combine data from image folder with excel which holds classification details in Keras

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, classification

I have a folder with 2400 images and one excel spreadsheet which holds two class classification details with image numbers. I want to do CNN on this with Keras.

Can you let me know how to combine this image files and excel to train the model?

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to extract the data from the spreadsheet. To do this, you'll want to export your spreadsheet to a `.csv` file. [This tutorial](http://nghiaho.com/?p=2333) has some more detailed information about extracting data from `.csv` files into keras.

If you already have knowledge about how neural networks work and some experience with python but need to learn how to use keras, I would suggest [this tutorial](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python). It's a great resource for getting started with keras and learning what it is capable of. That should get you started in the right direction, and then when you have more specific questions to ask we'll be able to help you more effectively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nelson , My excel has the image numbers along with 0,1 classification labels  and my image folder has the corresponding images.We generally have folders created for classes which is easier to do the classification task. If you understood my problem , can you please let me know how to tag the images with my y variables which is in csv file.